# D3.JS Force simulation collision issues

Tags: d3.js, graph, collision, force-layout

There is an updated version of this [gist](https://gist.github.com/colbenkharrl/21b3808492b93a21de841bc5ceac4e47). The blue node is a parent one, while orange are children. Basically, the task is to attract children to parent by adding links.

[image]

That's the outcome, I'm looking for, however sometimes children could be stopped and stuck by another green dots, like this

[image]

And that's really annoying. I'm not sure, but there's probably something wrong with collisions.

Any ideas?

```js
var graph;

var currentLinks = 1;

//  svg and sizing
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(function(d) { return 50;}))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(d => 10 + 10))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.select("#switch-btn").on("click", function() {
    
    currentLinks++;
    if(currentLinks > 5) { currentLinks = 1}
    update();
    
});
    
d3.select("#reset-btn").on("click", function() {
    
   location.reload();
    
});

var graph = {
    
    "nodes": [
        { "id": "0", "group": "2" },
        { "id": "1", "group": "3" },
        { "id": "2", "group": "3" },
        { "id": "3", "group": "1" },
        { "id": "4", "group": "1" },
        { "id": "5", "group": "3" },
        { "id": "6", "group": "3" },
        { "id": "7", "group": "1" },
        { "id": "8", "group": "1" },
        { "id": "9", "group": "1" },
        { "id": "10", "group": "1" },
        { "id": "11", "group": "1" },
        { "id": "12", "group": "1" },
        { "id": "13", "group": "1" },
        { "id": "14", "group": "1" },
        { "id": "15", "group": "1" },
        { "id": "16", "group": "1" },
        { "id": "17", "group": "1" }
    ],
    "links1": [
        { "source": "0", "target": "0", "id": "0"},
        { "source": "1", "target": "1", "id": "1"},
        { "source": "2", "target": "2", "id": "2"},
        { "source": "3", "target": "3", "id": "3"},
        { "source": "4", "target": "4", "id": "4"},
        { "source": "5", "target": "5", "id": "5"},
        { "source": "6", "target": "6", "id": "6"},
        { "source": "7", "target": "7", "id": "7"},
        { "source": "8", "target": "8", "id": "8"},
        { "source": "9", "target": "9", "id": "9"},
        { "source": "10", "target": "10", "id": "10"},
        { "source": "11", "target": "11", "id": "11"},
        { "source": "12", "target": "12", "id": "12"},
        { "source": "13", "target": "13", "id": "13"},
        { "source": "14", "target": "14", "id": "14"},
        { "source": "15", "target": "15", "id": "15"},
        { "source": "16", "target": "16", "id": "16"},
        { "source": "17", "target": "17", "id": "17"}
    ],
    "links2": [
        { "source": "0", "target": "5", "id": "0"}
        
    ],
    "links3": [
        { "source": "0", "target": "5", "id": "0"},
        { "source": "0", "target": "2", "id": "0"}
        
    ],
     "links4": [
        { "source": "0", "target": "5", "id": "0"},
        { "source": "0", "target": "2", "id": "0"},
        { "source": "0", "target": "6", "id": "0"}
        
    ],
    "links5": [
        { "source": "0", "target": "5", "id": "0"},
        { "source": "0", "target": "2", "id": "0"},
        { "source": "0", "target": "6", "id": "0"},
        { "source": "0", "target": "1", "id": "0"}
        
    ]
 };

update();
    
function reset() {
    
    link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");

    simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(function(d) { return 50;}))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(d => 10 + 10))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
    
    update();
    
}
    
function update() {

    link = link.data(graph["links" + currentLinks]);
        
    // Remove old links
    link.exit().remove();

    // Create new links as needed.  
    link = link.enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .merge(link);

    node = node.data(graph.nodes);

    node.exit().remove();

    node = node.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {return color(d.group);})
    .merge(node);

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes).on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link").links(graph["links" + currentLinks]);

    simulation.alphaTarget(.3).restart();
    
}

function ticked() {
    
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    
}
```

```css
.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
}

.node {
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link {
    stroke: gray;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
<button type="button" id="switch-btn">update bubbles</button>
<button type="button" id="reset-btn">reset</button>
</div>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```